# Got Error in Retrieving results using group by and order by in SQL server 2008

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, sql-server-2008, select

I am have a table with name Scripts which contains data of modified procedures, functions and tables.

```
CREATE TABLE #Scripts
    (
    ID              NUMERIC (18) IDENTITY NOT NULL, 
    [Date]          DATETIME NULL,
    DatabaseName    VARCHAR (50) NULL,
    Name            VARCHAR (100) NULL,
    Type            VARCHAR (20) NULL,
    Action          VARCHAR (50) NULL,
    Description     VARCHAR (500) NULL,
    ModifiedBy      VARCHAR (50) NULL,      
    AddedTimestamp  DATETIME NULL,
    UpdateTimestamp DATETIME NULL,  
    )
GO
```

And i added records into table as shown below. These are just sample records.

```
INSERT INTO #Scripts ([Date], DatabaseName, Name, Type, Action, Description, ModifiedBy, AddedTimestamp, UpdateTimestamp)
VALUES ('2015-01-07 11:16:41.4', 'Test', 'sp_GetData', 'Stored Procedure', 'Created', 'To Get ActivitySubscriptions for Mobile from tblSubscriptions', 'dinesh.alla', '2015-01-07 11:39:39.703', '2015-01-07 11:39:39.703')
GO

INSERT INTO #Scripts ([Date], DatabaseName, Name, Type, Action, Description, ModifiedBy, AddedTimestamp, UpdateTimestamp)
VALUES ('2015-01-07 11:16:41.4', 'Test', 'sp_GetData', 'Stored Procedure', 'Updated', 'To Get ActivitySubscriptions for Mobile from tblSubscriptions', 'dinesh.alla', '2015-01-07 11:39:39.703', '2015-01-07 11:39:39.703')
GO


INSERT INTO #Scripts ([Date], DatabaseName, Name, Type, Action, Description, ModifiedBy, AddedTimestamp, UpdateTimestamp)
VALUES ('2015-01-07 11:16:41.4', 'Test', 'sp_GetData', 'Stored Procedure', 'Deleted', 'To Get ActivitySubscriptions for Mobile from tblSubscriptions', 'dinesh.alla', '2015-01-07 11:39:39.703', '2015-01-07 11:39:39.703')
GO

INSERT INTO #Scripts ([Date], DatabaseName, Name, Type, Action, Description, ModifiedBy, AddedTimestamp, UpdateTimestamp)
VALUES ('2015-01-07 11:16:41.4', 'Test', 'sp_UpdateData', 'Stored Procedure', 'Created', 'To Get ActivitySubscriptions for Mobile from tblSubscriptions', 'dinesh.alla', '2015-01-07 11:39:39.703', '2015-01-07 11:39:39.703')
GO

INSERT INTO #Scripts ([Date], DatabaseName, Name, Type, Action, Description, ModifiedBy, AddedTimestamp, UpdateTimestamp)
VALUES ('2015-01-07 11:16:41.4', 'Test', 'sp_UpdateData', 'Stored Procedure', 'Updated', 'To Get ActivitySubscriptions for Mobile from tblSubscriptions', 'dinesh.alla', '2015-01-07 11:39:39.703', '2015-01-07 11:39:39.703')
GO

INSERT INTO #Scripts ([Date], DatabaseName, Name, Type, Action, Description, ModifiedBy, AddedTimestamp, UpdateTimestamp)
VALUES ('2015-01-07 11:16:41.4', 'Test', 'sp_AddData', 'Stored Procedure', 'Created', 'To Get ActivitySubscriptions for Mobile from tblSubscriptions', 'dinesh.alla', '2015-01-07 11:39:39.703', '2015-01-07 11:39:39.703')
GO
```

I tried to get results as shown below

```
SELECT MAX(ID) AS ID,MAX(Action) AS Action 
FROM #Scripts GROUP BY Name ORDER BY ID ASC
```

**Output:**

```
ID     Action
3      Updated
5      Updated
6      Created
```

**Expected Output:**

```
ID     Action
3      Deleted
5      Updated
6      Created
```

Comment: Why should it return "Deleted"? Are you trying to get last action performed? Then why not just use "SELECT TOP 1 * FROM #Scripts WHERE [Name] = 'sp_GetData' ORDER BY [ID] DESC"

Comment: when you ask for `max(action)` it will sort it alphabetically thats why showing `updated` rather than `deleted`. Just sort it with `max(id)`

Comment: The problem is you are try to take Max(string) trying to apply max function on varchar , so it will give output like above because when will you put values a,b into your table and  then try to take max then it will show b

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this:

```
 select distinct sc.action,sc.ID from (
  SELECT MAX(ID)  OVER(PARTITION BY NAME  ) rn,*  FROM #Scripts  
  )d  join #Scripts sc
  on d.rn=sc.ID
 order by sc.ID
```

**OUTPUT**

```
action  ID
Deleted 3
Updated 5
Created 6
```

Comment: that's not possible. Every time it will return only one record. I am having different names in NAME column.

Comment: @Dineshalla add more samples to your question and output

Comment: Now i think you understand my situation. @Ganesh_Devlekar

Comment: Thank You. Remaining queries also works fine but your query optimized bulk of my select query. @Ganesh_Devlekar

Answer (score 1):

```
;WITH LatestChanges AS
(
    SELECT  S.[ID], S.[Date], S.[DatabaseName], S.[Name], S.[Type], S.[Action], S.[Description],
            S.[ModifiedBy], S.[AddedTimestamp], S.[UpdateTimestamp],
            [RowNum] = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY S.[Name] ORDER BY S.[ID] DESC)
    FROM    [#Scripts] S
)
SELECT  *
FROM    LatestChanges
WHERE   [RowNum] = 1
ORDER BY ID
```

This returns last [ID] for each [Name].

Answer (score 0):

Supposing if you set two of the Actions to be 'a' and 'z' .. 
then the result of select max(Actions) will be z

If u want the expected output then you can try something like this

```
select TOP 1 MAX(ID) AS ID ,Action
FROM #Scripts where Name = 'sp_GetData'
GROUP BY Action
ORDER BY MAX(ID) DESC
```

Please go through [this](http://www.java2s.com/Tutorial/Oracle/0240__Aggregate-Functions/UseMAXwithstrings.htm) link you will get the concept

Answer (score 0):

TRY THIS,

```
SELECT * FROM 
(
   SELECT *,
   ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY NAME ORDER BY ID DESC )RN
   FROM @Scripts 
)T4
WHERE RN=1
```